# Как сбросить тригер

Tags: wpf

Вопрос такой, пользователь вводит текст, дальше, он нажимает на любое место в форме, и ввод текста больше не доступен.
Я понимаю что нужно использовать тригер, но какой, и как?

Comment: Вам нужен Event Trgger, загуглите в нете есть куча примеров.

Comment: @ПавелПопов Как лучше всего сделать? Через MouseLeave или как?

Answer (score 0):

Прмиерно вот так. А что бы отработало при нажатии на любой элемент на форме RoutedEvent="Mouse.PreviewMouseDown" но тогда не представляю как вы будете вводить текст, но вы сами так поставили задачу

```
   <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsEnabled"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="TextBox1">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Width="200" Height="50"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Ну а как тогда по иному убрать ввод текста?

Comment: @L1onelY я вам показал как это можно сделать исходя из того, что вы спросили. Я не знаю, что там у вас за элементы и почему вы решили сделать именно так, возможно  есть и другие варианты.... Из выше указанного примера вы можете далее развивать, то что вам нужно. Возможно поставить тригер не на window, а на что то иное.. я не знаю. Пытайтесь, что то сделать сами.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш вариант.